# How to get UK region using postcode?

Tags: php, json, curl

I want to get the UK region based on the postcode given using PHP. I have written as  $ch = curl_init();

```
$post="PR3 0SG";

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,  "https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/$post");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);

//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "limit=1");

$buffer = curl_exec($ch);

if(empty ($buffer))
{ 
   echo " buffer is empty "; 
}
else
{ 
   echo $buffer; 
}

curl_close($ch);
```

I get "buffer is empty" message. 
What's wrong with this! Is there any other way or script to get UK regions using postcode? I possible please provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You're not initializing the curl object (`$ch`) anywhere, you need to do that before actually using it.
2. You're sending a POST request and this API endpoint works with GET

   ```
   <?php
   $post = "PR3 0SG";
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/$post");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

   $buffer = curl_exec($ch);
   if (empty ($buffer)) {
       echo " buffer is empty ";
   } else {
       echo $buffer;
   }

   curl_close($ch);
   ```

Result:

```
{"status":200,"result":{"postcode":"PR3 0SG","quality":1,"eastings":351012,"northings":440283,"country":"England","nhs_ha":"North West","longitude":-2.74625152521674,"latitude":53.8564534479741,"parliamentary_constituency":"Wyre and Preston North","european_electoral_region":"North West","primary_care_trust":"North Lancashire Teaching","region":"North West","lsoa":"Wyre 006A","msoa":"Wyre 006","incode":"0SG","outcode":"PR3","admin_district":"Wyre","parish":"Myerscough and Bilsborrow","admin_county":"Lancashire","admin_ward":"Brock with Catterall","ccg":"NHS Lancashire North","nuts":"Lancaster and Wyre","codes":{"admin_district":"E07000128","admin_county":"E10000017","admin_ward":"E05009934","parish":"E04005340","ccg":"E38000093","nuts":"UKD44"}}}
```